# Print leap year for next 15 years from given year of input

Tags: python, loops, oop, if-statement, while-loop

I want to print next 15 leap years from the year given as input
as my code follows the control is stuck at the loop

```
def find_leap_years(given_year):
    list_of_leap_years=[]
    condition =given_year+15 
    while(given_year<=condition):
        if(given_year%4==0):
            list_of_leap_years.append(given_year)
        else:
            continue    
        given_year=given_year+1 
    print(list_of_leap_years)    
    

    # Write your logic here

    return list_of_leap_years

list_of_leap_years=find_leap_years(2000)
print(list_of_leap_years)
```

**The expected output is to print leap years for next upcoming 15 year from the given value**
*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Do you want to print the next 15 leap years or the leap years that happen over the next 15 years? Your code seems to attempt to do the second one

Comment: The loop does not exceeds one iteration and the expected output is not obtained

Comment: i want to print the leap years for the next 15 years from the given value

Comment: A `while` loop is needlessly complicated to use here.  Try `for year in range(given_year, given_year+15):` instead.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding your

```
else:
        continue
```

let's you loop infinite times over the year 2000. Get rid of it. Then you get

```
[2000, 2004, 2008, 2012]
```